# SendGrid API throws exception

Tags: sendgrid

How to send mail using sendgrid API from console application?. I have referred this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/#create-a-sendgrid-account.
It throws

> "api access for mail not allowed"

Comment: Hi there, can you please open a ticket with SendGrid support about this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question. How to check whether my sendgrid account has API access or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sendgrid account not having "Mail" access, so only it shows that exception. From admin account now access given and everything works fine.

Thanks,
Rahini.